# PHP Mutiple Inheritance on symfony2 entities. Right way

Tags: php, oop, symfony, multiple-inheritance

I have 2 Abstract classes: AbstractCommentable (methods for comments) and AbstractImaging (entity methods for manage images).

Some classes already have:

```
class Trip extends AbstractImaging {/** some stuff **/}
class Marker extends AbstractImaging {/** some stuff **/}
class Gastronomy extends AbstractImaging {/** some stuff **/}
```

But I want to add AbstractCommentable to this classes...

What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to make `AbstractImaging` already extend `AbstractCommentable` or other way around ... which i suggest you don't want.

Multiple inheritance can only be linear in PHP because of possible conflicts.

You can't do something like ...

```
class Whatever extends AbstractImaging, AbstractCommentable
```

**The easy way:**

If you're using php 5.4+ you could use a trait to add the CommentableInterface methods to your entity.

**The complicated way:**

create an annotation and let a doctrine-listener create a proxy class adding the commentable methods.

Comment: Complicated way looks better... I'm gonna try

Comment: finally I created my own behaviors (traits)

Comment: jeah it's the quick way and used in a few bundle's like KnpDoctrineBehaviors aswell ... though not smoothly testable :D

Comment: the problem now is... the trait Commentable have a @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="?????") I can't set mapped by... ;-(